# Grabbing Json with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

I have some JSON i am trying grab and loop through, my initial code is below accessing the following JSON. https://textdoc.co/lJAxGYXgcZ9V4NUB

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = "<URL REMOVED"
response = urlopen(url)

data_json = json.loads(response.read())

#loop and grab data for G
for i in data_json[0]["data"]:
    print(f'Date:  {i[0]} , Value : {i[1]}')

#loop and grab data for I
for i in data_json[1]["data"]:
    print(f'Date:  {i[0]} , Value : {i[1]}')

#loop and grab data for E
for i in data_json[2]["data"]:
    print(f'Date:  {i[0]} , Value : {i[1]}')

#loop and grab data for C
for i in data_json[3]["data"]:
    print(f'Date:  {i[0]} , Value : {i[1]}')

#loop and grab data for SC
for i in data_json[4]["data"]:
    print(f'Date:  {i[0]} , Value : {i[1]}')
```

The issue i have is i'm getting TypeError on the for loop saying "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

I'm a little confused by this as i thought json.loads would deserialise it into an object that i could iterate over?

Comment: reviewing this again (typically straight after posting), i think the issue is with ["[0].data"] on the loop. 

Do i have the correct syntax? Intent is for to be a starter point for the nest of data to be looped through.

Comment: Further to add, i have updated the following line
for i in data_json["[0].data"]: to for i in data_json["0"]: to get the first nested loop but i still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue now, i was treating the 0 or 1 in the JSON as strings, when in actual fact i shouldn't have been. i removed the double quotes and it now works for the first line....

As i have answered this myself i will update the questions to reflect the updated problem.